# Launch application after auto-update the app without any user interaction

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have made an iOS application. In this application, I want that the application should relaunch automatically after it gets auto-updated on the iPhone device without any user interaction.

Kindly let me know if this is possible.

Comment: An app can't be launched automatically. User interaction is required.

Answer (score 1):

An application can't be launched by its own. User interaction is required for updating or relaunching.

Answer (score 0):

Launching AppStore application. by openURL of appstore://yourappid

That is not possible with out user interacting the device. Because user have to click update button in AppStore application.

then only user will get latest updated application.

Comment: Right, but apart from this we can give a setting for an auto-updating application in the Setting menu under 'iTunes and App Stores', there has automatic "Updates" option.